Extended Monty Hall Question with computer
Question: You are the contestant on the Monty Hall show. Monty is trying out a new version of
his game, with rules as follows. You get to choose one of three doors. One door has a car
behind it, another has a computer, and the other door has a goat (with all permutations
equally likely). Monty, who knows which prize is behind each door, will open a door (but
not the one you chose) and then let you choose whether to switch from your current
choice to the other unopened door.
Assume that you prefer the car to the computer, the computer to the goat, and (by
transitivity) the car to the goat.
(a) Suppose for this part only that Monty always opens the door that reveals your less
preferred prize out of the two alternatives, e.g., if he is faced with the choice between
revealing the goat or the computer, he will reveal the goat. Monty opens a door, revealing
a goat (this is again for this part only). Given this information, should you switch? If
you do switch, what is your probability of success in getting the car?
(b) Now suppose that Monty reveals your less preferred prize with probability p, and
your more preferred prize with probability q = 1− p. Monty opens a door, revealing a
computer. Given this information, should you switch (your answer can depend on p)?
If you do switch, what is your probability of success in getting the car (in terms of p)?
My Solution
For a), I got an answer of $\frac{1}{2}$ because if a goat has been revealed, there are 2 cases left - you have the computer or you have the car probability of getting the car if you switch is $\frac{1}{2}$.
For b), I got an answer of $2p$. My reasoning is as follows:

Let $G$ be the goat, $C_a$ be the car and $C_o$ is the computer. Then a sequence like $G, C_a, C_o$ would mean that the goat is in door 1, car is in door 2 and computer is in door 3.
WLOG assume that we chose door 1. Then given that a goat has been revealed, we are left with the following situations:
$G, C_a, C_o$ and $G, C_o, C_a$ are both situations in which there was a probabiltiy $p$ that a computer was revealed.
$C_a, G, C_o$ and $C_a, C_o, G$ are btoh situations where there was a probability $1-p$ that a computer was revealed.
So the probability of success in getting the car if you switch is the probabilties of the first 2 cases occurring which is $p + p = 2p$ divided by $p + p + (1 - p) + (1 - p) = 2$ which gives an answer of $p$.

Does anyone know of an easier way to solve part b) instead of just going case by case?

To clarify:  in $b)$, Monty has no problem revealing the top prize if you didn't choose that initially?  Or is it that, when he can, he chooses between the two lesser prizes with some probability?   In any case, I expect that going through the cases is your best bet.

How about the statement: "Someone who switches will win the car if and only if his original choice was not for the door that hides the car. The probability of this event is 2/3". Isn't this still valid in both cases (as it is in the original Monty Hall problem)?

@drhab That statement is not true. These games are different from the original Monty Hall problem, because differentiation of the "undesired" doors gives information about the initial choice, where there was none in the original problem. For example, if Monty reveals a computer, I know that I didn't initially pick the door hiding the computer.

@K.Jiang Is the statement that a switcher wins iff his original was wrong a false statement then? Can you describe a situation in which this clearly appears to be false then? Something like: he has chosen wrong originally, then switches but still does not win the car. Or: he has chosen the door that hides the car, then switches but still wins the car.

@drhab That part of the statement is true and useful to approach these problems (instead of thinking about probability of winning after switching, it's easier to think about the probability of having initially picked a door hiding a specific prize). I just don't think that the probability of (not initially picking the car door) here is $\frac{2}{3}$ as it is in the original version of the game.

@K.Jiang For me: P(winning car|switch)=P(wrong original choice)=2/3. This in spite of the added info.

@drhab Take the version in (a). $P (\text{computer initial choice} | \text{goat revealed}) \color{red}{\ne} \frac{2}{3}$. This is a direct application of Bayes. If the computer was the initial choice, Monty would show the goat. If the car was the initial choice, Monty would still show the goat. The two cases are indistinguishable. So $P (\text{computer initial choice} | \text{goat revealed}) = \color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}$.

@K.Jiang I will have a look at that (later, now is less convenient). Beware though that uptil now I am only saying things about P(winning car|switch). Not about P(switch).Thank you and cheers.

Please could you answer the questions posed by @lulu in the first comment on your question?

i dont understand the question - there will always be the option to choose a lesser prize in any scenario and he will do that with probability p

@Apex345 In the normal Monty Hall problem it is excluded that Monty reveals a car. Is that also the case in your problem? Personally I took that for granted in my answer but it is not explicitly stated in your question. So possibly my answer should be deleted.

it says that he reveals your more preferred prize with probability 1-p so yes there is a chance he reveals the car if for example you chose a door with the goat

@Apex345 Thank you. My answer is deleted now.

For (a), we can calculate the probability of a goat getting revealed. There is no way that we initially picked the goat. If we initially picked either the computer or the car (each with probability $\frac{1}{3}$), then the goat is shown with probability $1$. So you are correct that the posterior probability of our initial guess being the computer is
$$\frac{\frac{1}{3} (1)}{\frac{1}{3} (1) + \frac{1}{3} (1)} = \frac{1}{2}$$
as you have found.
We can apply similar reasoning for (b). If the computer was revealed, there is no way that we could have initially picked it. If we initially picked the car (probability $\frac{1}{3}$), the computer is revealed with probability $1 - p$, since it is preferred to the goat. If we initially picked the goat (probability $\frac{1}{3}$), the computer is revealed with probability $p$, since it is less preferred than the car. So the posterior probability of our initial guess being the goat is
$$\frac{\frac{1}{3} p}{\frac{1}{3} p + \frac{1}{3} (1 - p)} = p$$
In such a scenario, switching would give us the car with probability $p$. We should therefore switch when $\boxed{p \ge \frac{1}{2}}$; i.e., when Monty is more likely to reveal the less-preferred prize.

Do I understand correctly from this that it is better not to switch if e.g. $p=0$? If so then I do not agree because - if Monty shows the most preferred prize (i.e. $p=0$) - he will show a computer if you pick initially a goat but also if you initially pick a car.

@drhab If you initially pick the door hiding the goat, the host shows the car (because the car is more preferred over the computer). Nowhere in the rules does it say the host cannot reveal the car (this is a rule in the original game, but not here - unless I am missing something).

Oh, I see. That means that my view on the problem was misformed. I regret that. Also my answer is useless then . I will wait some period and if no further info arrives then I will delete my answer.

You are right. See the last comments on the question.
